# How to update or read TextFiled inside GridLayout which is in TabView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have below stack of components and I want to read and set value of the TextFiled:

```
-Rectangle
-----TabView
---------Tab
-----------Rectangle 
--------------GridLayout
------------------Rectangle 
--------------------TextField <--- I want to access this TextField
```

I have also a case where I need to access Repeater inside the Tab:

```
-Rectangle
-----TabView
---------Tab
-----------Rectangle 
--------------GridLayout
------------------Repeater 
--------------------TextField <--- I want to access this TextField also
```

I have tried to access it using:

```
var tab0 = myTabView.getTab(0);
tab0.children[0].text = "Some Text"; // I get Undefined Error
```

I have tried to access the component using a function inside the `Tab`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14 as QQC2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.14
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as QQC1

QQC2.Item {

QQC1.TabView {

  QQC1.Tab {
    title: "tab1"

    function printValue ()  {
      console.log("myTextFld.txt: "+myTextFld.txt);  // <-- Getting Error myTextFld undefined.
    }

    Rectangle {
      id: tabHolderRext
      color: "blue"

      GridLayout {
        id: myGrid
        model: 7

        Repeater {
          id: herderRepeater
          model: header
          delegate: Rectangle {
            TextField {
              // I want to Access This TextField also 
            }
          }
        }

        Rectangle {
          id: row0Rect
          Layout.row: 0
          Layout.column: index

          TextFiled {
            id: myTextFld
            text: modelData
          }     
        }

        // Rest of the rows 
    }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: The old `TabView` use kind of lazy loading concept. Use [TabBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tabbar.html) with [StackLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-stacklayout.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Item `id` can be used to access the values from TextField if you have all items in same qml file. If you have different qml files then make use of `alias types` [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#:~:text=Property%20Aliases&text=Unlike%20an%20ordinary%20property%2C%20an,which%20the%20alias%20is%20declared.&text=It%20cannot%20refer%20to%20objects,the%20scope%20of%20its%20type.) to access the values.

Repeater case: The Textfield has to update the underlying model`view --> model` first then we can make use of the model's data.

Here is a sample code. I have stacked all item's in the same qml file so that access by id works here.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        TabView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Tab {
                title: "TextField"

                Item {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    Grid {
                        spacing: 20
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: 10
                        Rectangle {
                            height: 40
                            width: 150
                            TextField {
                                id: inputId
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                placeholderText: "enter text"
                            }
                        }

                        Button {
                            height: 40
                            width: 150
                            text: "show txt"
                            onClicked: labelId.text = inputId.text
                        }

                        Rectangle {
                            height: 40
                            width: 150
                            Label {
                                id: labelId
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Tab {
                title: "Repeater"

                Item {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    Grid {
                        spacing: 20
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: 10
                        columns: 3

                        ListModel {
                            id: fruitModel
                            ListElement { name: "Apple" }
                            ListElement { name: "Orange" }
                            ListElement { name: "Banana" }
                        }

                        Repeater {
                            width: parent.width
                            height: parent.height / 2
                            model: fruitModel
                            delegate: Rectangle {
                                height: 40
                                width: 150
                                TextField {
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    text: name
                                    onTextChanged: fruitModel.setProperty(index, "name", text) // update model data
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Repeater {
                            width: parent.width
                            height: parent.height / 2
                            model: fruitModel
                            delegate: Rectangle {
                                height: 40
                                width: 150
                                Label {
                                    text: name
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```